# ArchUnit: cyclic dependency for generics not detected

Tags: archunit

ArchUnit 0.14.1 did not detect cyclic dependencies for types that are used as parameters for generic fields. Is that a limitation in ArchUnit or am I doing something wrong? , e. g.:

```
package com.test.a;
import com.test.b.B;

public class A {
    protected B b;
}
```

```
package com.test.b;
import java.util.Optional;
import com.test.a.A;

public class B {
    protected Optional<A> a; // not detected by archunit
    // protected A a2; // detected by archunit
}
```

```
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.test")
public class ArchitecturalChecks {

    @ArchTest
    public void testNoCycles(JavaClasses importedClasses) {
        SlicesRuleDefinition.slices().matching("com.test.(*)..").should().beFreeOfCycles().check(importedClasses);
    }

    @ArchTest
    public void testPackageStructure(JavaClasses importedClasses) {
        // @formatter:off
        Architectures.layeredArchitecture()
            .layer("A").definedBy("com.test.a..")
            .layer("B").definedBy("com.test.b..")
            .whereLayer("A").mayNotBeAccessedByAnyLayer()
            .whereLayer("B").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("A")
            .check(importedClasses);
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArchUnit does currently (as of [version](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases) 0.16.0) unfortunately not [fully support generics](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/115) yet, but this is being worked on.
(For instance, [ArchUnit 0.16.0](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases/tag/v0.16.0) would, unlike previous versions, already detect the dependency for `class B extends ArrayList<A>`.)

I'm confident that some future release of ArchUnit will detect dependencies via generic type parameters of fields, as the information *is* actually present in the byte code, see `javap -v B.class`:

```
public class com.test.b.B
  minor version: 0
  major version: 55
  flags: (0x0021) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
  this_class: #2                          // com/test/b/B
  super_class: #3                         // java/lang/Object
  interfaces: 0, fields: 1, methods: 1, attributes: 1
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #3.#14         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #15            // com/test/b/B
   #3 = Class              #16            // java/lang/Object
   #4 = Utf8               a
   #5 = Utf8               Ljava/util/Optional;                  // <- erased type of a
   #6 = Utf8               Signature
   #7 = Utf8               Ljava/util/Optional<Lcom/test/a/A;>;  // <- generic type of a
   #8 = Utf8               <init>
   #9 = Utf8               ()V
  #10 = Utf8               Code
  #11 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #12 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #13 = Utf8               B.java
  #14 = NameAndType        #8:#9          // "<init>":()V
  #15 = Utf8               com/test/b/B
  #16 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  protected java.util.Optional<com.test.a.A> a;
    descriptor: Ljava/util/Optional;
    flags: (0x0004) ACC_PROTECTED
    Signature: #7                           // Ljava/util/Optional<Lcom/test/a/A;>;

  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, will give it a try

Comment: I think [ArchUnit 0.19.0](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases/tag/v0.19.0) had added the support for generic field types, and the [current release](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases/) 0.22.0 has even more!

Answer (score 0):

ArchUnit is doing it's job by analyzing given [Java bytecode](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_introduction).

Generics are a subject of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so there will be not type information in the examined bytecode, where your field will be intrepreted as `Optional<Object> a` hence no cycle detected.